# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher')

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I know that this question is there few times, but I can´t find answer for my case.

my folder '@drawable is empty, but even if i change it to another like mipmap - becou there is scaled icon (i dont know why are in this folder and not in drawable).

but if I change it and do build or clean or synch with gradle, I keep getting  same eror and the line in manifest it keep geting reset to android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher".

Question is maybe little messy, but I dont know what to do :( thanks

Comment: Did you delete the 'ic_launcher.png' file from your drawable folder?

Comment: drawable folder is and was empty. But I copy code to another project..and it´s working fine...:) I don´t what was that..:-/

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you are using Android Studio as your IDE. [Starting in Android Studio version 1.1](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio11preview1released), launcher icons are placed in mipmap folders. You are getting the error because you are looking for the launcher icon in the wrong folder.

Change

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

To

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Comment: In question I wrote that I tried this.. but it keeps geting reset ti original state. So after I changed to android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" and do clean or rebuld.. it resets again to android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher". This was problem. But like I said, I copy code to another project and it´s working fine. Strange.

Comment: @John this is not a solution of the problem. I'm facing this problem since i upgrade dependencies.